# rails actionmailer with confirmable link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, devise-confirmable

I used `Actionmailer` in my rails app to send an email of welcoming and link to the app but in the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html there is not confirmable like devise :

`devise :registerable, :confirmable`
Then, do the migration as:
`rails g migration add_confirmable_to_devise`

Is there is a way to do it or must I delete my `ActionMailer` and Use `devise :confirmable` ?

Answer (score 0):

Actionmailer gives you the basic framework for creating & sending your email from within a Rails app. 
It doesn't come with features like 'confirmable'.

You would have to code that functionality, or use devise gem with the :confirmable module enabled.